# How do I reset the zoom level in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, zoom

How do I reset the zoom level in Firefox back to the default?

Comment: Is it `Ctrl`+`0`? I ask as a comment because I don't have FF handy to test. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Select *View » Zoom » Reset* from the menu.

Alternatively press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> on Mac OS X, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> on Windows and Linux.

Comment: The menu no longer exists in Firefox, but the keyboard shortcut still works.

Comment: @BurhanAli Still exists on Firefox 23 on OS X and Firefox 20 on Windows. What version and OS are you referring to?

Comment: My mistake. It seems the standard menu bar is hidden now until you hit Alt. I don't use Firefox regularly enough these days so to me it looked like the menu bar was no longer there at all.

Answer (score 11):

Go to `View > Zoom > reset`
alternatively you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>

Answer (score 8):

Go to "View" in the menu, then "Zoom" and then "Normal". Or just press '`Ctrl + 0`' (Zero)

Answer (score 6):

To reset the zoom level on all pages go to `about:config` and set `browser.zoom.siteSpecific` to `false`.

Comment: Probably the only practicable solution on Firefox mobile since it has no View menu and no CTRL key!

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me

about:config
on layout.css.devPixelsPerPx to modify its value. The default is -1.0 in Firefox 22 and above. Change it to 1.0 to make it work like in previous Firefox versions.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/963759

Search page for layout.css.devPixelsPerPx